# Is there a way to submit a form which then submits another form for me?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to send an OTP to a certain phone number which is being fetched from a mySQL database using PHP. The way it works currently:

**1.** User enters an email and clicks login button.

**2.** A OTP is randomly generated and stored in DB.

**3.** phone number associated with email retrieved.

However, the SMS service I use uses a form to submit the data to a third party sending file. My problem is that I need to retrieve the data first, then use that data as parameters for my other form and submit it. But I don't know if I can do all of that with just a single button.

Below is my form which calls the login file.

```html
<form action="login.php" method="POST">
  <div class="form-signin">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading"></h2>
    <?php if ($_REQUEST['s'] == 't') { ?>
    <label for="clientToken" class="sr-only">Verification Code</label>
    <input type="text" name="clientToken" id="clientToken" class="form-control" placeholder="6 digit Token" required autofocus><br>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <label for="clientEmail" class="sr-only">Email</label>
    <input type="text" autocomplete="clientEmail" name="clientEmail" id="clientEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required autofocus><br>
    <?php } ?>
    <input class="btn btn-lg btn-danger btn-block" type="submit" value="Login"></input><br>
    <?php if ($_REQUEST['s'] == 'f') { ?>
    <div class="text-center text-white">No such email exists in our records</div>
    <?php } ?>
  </div>
</form>
```

Below is the form which calls the SMS sending service, which I am trying to send after the login.php file has finished retrieving data from the mySQL DB.

```html
<form id="sms" action="https://api.silverstreet.com/send.php" method="post">
  <table align="center">
    <tr style="display: none">
      <td>Username</td>
      <td>: <input type="text" name="username" value="name" readonly="readonly"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display: none">
      <td>Password</td>
      <td>: <input type="text" name="password" value="pass" readonly="readonly"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display: none">
      <td>Destination</td>
      <td>: <input type="text" name="destination" value="number"> Eg: 60125555555</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display: none">
      <td>Sender</td>
      <td>: <input type="text" name="sender" value="name"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display: none">
      <td>Body</td>
      <td>: <textarea name="body" rows="4" cols="50">OTP here</textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display: none">
      <td align="center" colspan="2"><input type="submit"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Is there a way that I would be able to make this work? Or would I need two separate buttons?

Comment: Try php curl to get data from the first URL

Comment: PHP curl or you might want to call the function of sending SMS in login.php so you can send it once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use php curl to submit the form (or send request) from your server.

In `login.php`, after retrieving the information from database, you can submit curl request like following code:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.silverstreet.com/send.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, http_build_query(
    array(
        "username" => "<username>",
        "password" => "<password>",
        "sender" => "hello",
        "body" => "hello world.",
        "destination" => "1234567890,1234567891"
    )
));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if(curl_errno($ch)){ echo curl_errno($ch); }
curl_close($ch));
?>
```

Reference: https://www.silverstreet.com/api-documents/?php#portal-sms-submit

Comment: I've been trying this for some time now, but it seems like it doesn't send the SMS, and echoing the curl_errno doesn't do print anything as well. Is there a way to retrieve the response code from php curl?

Comment: Ah okay it says 100 (Parameters missing), does that mean there are more parameters needed in the array?

Comment: Owh, seems like their site is wrong, had to replace the second RETURNTRANSFER with a POSTFIELDS, thanks buddy